# Circular saw blade type

Tags: table-saw

I picked up a used small circular saw , the type that would be like a small bench saw, or table saw, the other day. It has a blade with tungsten teeth around it, but the label says the saw is for ceramics - tiles, etc. I thought blades for those would have no teeth, but be diamond tipped or suchlike. There's no facility for water to be used with it. Does it appear that someone has changed the blade to enable it to cut wood, or can tiles be cut with tungsten carbide teeth? Reticent to try a tile, as that may just knock some teeth about!

Comment: Teeth and tiles usually do not like each other.  Most types of saw blades can fit on a saw if it is the same size, so you can put a diamond tile blade on a wood cutting saw, but do not know if a tile saw has the right power for wood(possible).  Usually tile saws use smaller diameter blades, so wood cutting size would be limited.

Comment: Do you know if the teeth are in the right rotation for cutting wood?  Have heard a long time ago that sometimes putting the blade on backwards could work on hard breakable materials.  Never tried it, do not know if it even works.

Comment: The label you are looking at is presumably on the machine, not the blade? If the blade is labeled for tile, it's a tile blade, whatever it looks like. If the machine is labeled for tile, it has no idea what someone put in it for a wrong blade...and that seems like the most likely case here. So remove the blade and look at its labeling/marking. While you are doing that you might find wood sawdust.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - good idea. Found lots of tile dust so far. Machine itself is labelled 'tile cutter'.

Comment: I have once or twice seen a blade that was labeled for ceramics that had teeth.  On closer examination the teeth were formed differently from a wood blade, and apparently were there just to help move the dust out.

Comment: A picture of the blade/teeth would help to positively say if for wood or tile.  Most saws just there to spin blades to cut stuff.  A tile blade makes the saw a tile saw, a wood type blade makes the saw for wood cutting.